What does the Maximum Principle tell us when $\lambda'(t)=0$?
Consider an optimal control problem where $u(t)$ is the control and $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ are states. The law of motion for $x(t)$ is $x'(t)=u(t)$. The law of motion for $y(t)$ is $y'(t)=x(t)$. We are choosing the control to maximize:
$$
\int_0^1 f(y(x),x(t),t)dt.
$$
The Hamiltonian for this problem looks as follows:
$$
H(y,x,u,t,\lambda) = f(y,x,t) + \lambda \cdot u + \eta \cdot x
$$
Suppose we know a solution $(y^*,x^*,u^*)$ exists, and that at that solution $\lambda'(t)=0$ at some $t$. Then the Pontryagin Maximum Principle tells us that:
$$
\lambda'(t)=0 = -\frac{\partial}{\partial x}H^*
$$
Which gives:
$$
0 = f_x(y^*(t),x^*(t),t)+\eta(t)
$$
That is, if we evaluate the Hamiltonian at $y^*(t),t$ and $\eta(t)$ and think of it as a function of $x$, then the solution $x^*(t)$ is a critical point of the Hamiltonian. But can we conclude that this critical point is not its local minimum? The statement of the PMP does not make such a claim, but it seems intuitively true.

If $f(x)= x^3 $ then the only critical point is neither a local maximum nor a local minimum.

Good point, I should have said 'not a local minimum'

The Hamiltonian is a function of more variables. So your question is similar to asking if $x=0$ is a local minimum of $g(x,y)=x^2+y^2$, to which the answer is no. Partial derivatives with respect to all input variables should be zero in order for it to be a potential local minima.

Thanks. I should again clarify. I mean to ask about the local minimum when looking at it only as a function of $x$ (so evaluated at $y^*$ and $t$).
